# c# compiling, reference to another class

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, reference, csc

I have a problem in compiling an `.cs` file in the windows cmd.

I have a class `Client.cs` and in this class I use an instance of another class `Student.cs` (they are in the same package so no using/import needed).

I successfully compiled the Client.cs file with the `Student.cs` instance not used as follows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe Client.cs
```

When decomment the line where i use the instance of that class i get the following error message when compiling :

```
Client.cs(29,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Student' could not
        be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My question is how can i compile my Client.cs file with the compiler "knowing" about that Student.cs.
I should add that in Visual Studio it works well. Thank you.

Comment: try importing "using [namespacename].Student"

Comment: Both classes are in the same package, VS don't even let me to use "using... " with the second class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile both files at the same time:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe Client.cs Student.cs
```

otherwise the compiler won't know that the class Student even exists.